# Python: Pandas Dataframe If ColA is Blank and ColB Contains String then New Column Says String

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, nan

EDITED QUESTION

---

I have the sample table below:

```
colA        colB
ABC         IAH
DEADFSLJ    CI
            CI
            CI
AFDSJLKA222 CI
23940281    CI
```

I want to employ the following logic: 
If colA is blank / empty string and colB is CI then create a new column (ColC) that says Incomplete.  Otherwise, new column says Complete.

The logic should produce the following table:

```
colA        colB    colC
ABC         IAH     Complete
DEADFSLJ    CI      Complete
            CI      Incomplete
            CI      Incomplete 
AFDSJLKA222 CI      Complete 
23940281    CI      Complete
```

Below is the code I tried:

```
df_EVENT5_28['colC'] = np.where((df_EVENT5_28['colA'] == '') & (df_EVENT5_28['colB'] == 'CI'), 'Incomplete', 'Complete')
```

The code runs but produces the following error: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Thoughts?

Comment: The value doesn't seem to be NaN. It can be empty str. Maybe try: `df_EVENT5_28['colC'] = np.where((df_EVENT5_28['colA'] == '') & (df_EVENT5_28['colB'] == 'CI'), 'Incomplete', 'Complete')`
`

Answer (score 1):

`NaN == NaN` evaluate as False.

Use `isnull()`

```
 np.where((df_EVENT5_28['colA'].isnull()) & (df_EVENT5_28['colB'] == 'CI'), 'Incomplete', 'Complete')
```